# A prerequisite for "An Introduction to Algebraic Topology" by Rotman

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

I am a graduate student who wants to study algebraic geometry,but also needs very much to learn basic graduate topology.Someone told me that Rotman is the best option in this case.However,i tried to read it and i really stucked at the very first pages(it was really tough the way rotman introduces straight abstract definitions) so i thought that i should fill in all the further gaps that might have(with maybe more examples or a historical approach of the subject to get the feeling).I was wondering if there is an undergraduate text on algebraic topology that is a very suitable begining of understanding Rotman.If it's possible i want books that contain content very similar to Rotman's book(with maybe more explanations of course).

Comment: I would recommend Massey.

Comment: it is still a graduate text.Are you sure that i would not have any problem with it?

Comment: there aren't very many algebraic-topology texts marketed for undergrads, other than Hatcher which some beginners have a hard time with. Massey is very hands-on, and introduces a lot of higher/advanced concepts through the basic material. (I read the first few chapters of Massey in undergrad and found it very helpful.) There is also "Elements of Algebraic Topology" by Munkres which only deals with (co)homology, and is very detail-oriented

Comment: So the prerequisites for Massey are only basic differential geometry and undergraduate algebra?

Comment: I would say it requires no differential geometry whatsoever, other than Appendix A on deRham's theorem. It only needs undergrad algebra and point-set topology